# Can't change a variables attributes in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I haven't used Rails in a while and there's something I want to clear up.

So the `@` symbol indicated that, that *specific* variable will be accessible within that controllers view. Correct?

Meaning if I have a route

`get '/admin/user:id' to: 'admin#user'`

This means that whenever, I go to the route, it's going to go to the route `'/admin/user:id'` and then it will have access to all the `@variables` in that controller. Correct?

Now this is a small problem I have, that would normally be a simple `if-statement` in JavaScript.

For example, say I have a `User` model and I want to show a small `Friend`'s list with the friends `.first_name`, `last_name`, `favourite_food`. I can show this by simply doing

*admins_controller*

```
def user 
    @user = user.find_by(:id => params[:id])
end
```

And then in my *views* have something like

```
<h1><%= @user.name %>'s Friends List</h1>
<table>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.first.friend.first_name %></tr>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.first.friend.last_name %></tr>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.first.friend.favourite_food %></tr>
</table>
```

My **problem** is that **if** they don't have friends, I want to set everything to "N/A". This is how I was going about it in my controller.

```
def user 
  @user = user.find_by(:id => params[:id])
  if @user.friends.nil?
    @user.user_friends.first.friend.name = "N/A"
    @user.user_friends.first.friend.name = "N/A"
    @user.user_friends.first.friend.name = "N/A"
  end
end
```

I guess I could create another `@variable` but, I am assuming this would be a better approach because it's not good to create unnecessary wide scoped variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will put that logic directly on the view, with a ternary operator, like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.nil? ? "N/A" : @user.user_friends.first.friend.first_name %></tr>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.nil? ? "N/A" : @user.user_friends.first.friend.last_name %></tr>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.nil? ? "N/A" : @user.user_friends.first.friend.favourite_food %></tr>
</table>
```

And keep your controller slim:

```
def user 
  @user = user.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about this. Yeah, the controllers we have are about 60 lines right now, but it's a lot of mathematics and converting seconds, dates, etc.

Comment: If you are converting only for display purposes, you should move that logic into your view (and, better yet, into view helpers).

Comment: `user.find(params[:id])` is enough

Answer (score 1):

This logic belongs in the view, do something like this

```
<% if @user.user_friends.any? %>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.first.friend.first_name %></tr>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.first.friend.last_name %></tr>
  <tr><%= @user.user_friends.first.friend.favourite_food %></tr>  
<% else %>
  <tr>N/A</tr>
  <tr>N/A</tr>
  <tr>N/A</tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use the `presenter` pattern in a case like this. So, in your controller you would do something like:

```
def user 
  @user = user.find_by(:id => params[:id])
  @user_presenter = UserPresenter.new(self)
end
```

Then in your view you would do something like:

```
<h1><%= @user.name %>'s Friends List</h1>
@user_presenter.friends_list
```

I like doing it this way because:

- My views have *zero* knowledge about my model layer (I like the separation)
- It makes my views super-dumb (no logic in the view, which I prefer - in my apps, views have *only* html mark up (I use HAML) and calls to presenters)
- If I make any changes to my models, I don't have to go back into my view and make changes (as long as my `UserPresenter` honors the `friends_list` interface)
- I find it a whole lot easier to test plain old ruby objects (all my `Presenters` are POROs) than testing various Rails components (controllers, views, etc.)

There is a good [RailsCast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U) on Presenters.

Answer (score 1):

In that domain you have two entities: UserWithFriends and UserWithoutFriends. So you need to create a UserFactory

```
class UserWithFriends < User
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end
  def friend_first_name
    @user.friends.first.first_name
  end
  def friend_last_name
    @user.friends.first.last_name
  end
  def friend_favourite_food
    @user.friends.first.favourite_food
  end

end

class UserWithoutFriends < User
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end
  def friend_first_name
   "N/A"
  end
  def friend_last_name
    "N/A"
  end
  def friend_favourite_food
    "N/A"
  end
end


class UserFactory
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def create
    if @user.friends.any?
      UserWithFriends(@user).new
    else
      UserWithoutFriends(@user).new
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller

```
def user 
    @user = UserFactory.new(user.find_by(:id => params[:id])).create
end
```

So, in the view you simply do

```
<h1><%= @user.name %>'s Friends List</h1>
<table>
  <tr><%= @user.friend_first_name %></tr>
  <tr><%= @user.friend_last_name %></tr>
  <tr><%= @user.friend_favourite_food %></tr>
</table>
```